# Setting up catch-all with iptables

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables

I'm trying to setup a iptables which only allows traffic in via ssh and a catch all that blocks everything else coming into computer.  The iptables -L output looks like this

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The above appears to block anything coming into the computer except for SSH, however, it also seems to block returning traffic from an outgoing request.  i.e. if I try to ping www.google.com it seems to time trying to resolve DNS.  I'm assuming my DROP all blocking the response from the DNS request.

Can anyone direct me how to setup the catch-all correctly to allow returning traffic back in?

Thank you,

Matthew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED` to match returning traffic. Also, you don't have to include a "drop all" rule, just change INPUT's chain policy to "DROP".

```
sudo iptables -F INPUT
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```